VPC Endpoint Policy for VPC Attached Lambda Functions
I am running several Lambda functions within my VPC, and want to configure VPC endpoints for private access to certain services (secretsmanager, s3, etc.). My goal is to lock down the VPC endpoint so that only requests from within my VPC can use it. However, I am having a lot of trouble trying to specify this within the policy.
I am unable to explicitly set the lambda function's role due to the structure of our projects in Terraform.
I have tried using the aws:sourceVpc condition as well as several others, however they all block the Lambda's access to the VPC endpoint.
Are there any other conditions I could use? I would really prefer to not have a complete Allow statement as the policy.

If you are having problems with your Lambda function's role, you should provide more details here or in a supplemental question once you've resolved the VPC endpoint policy question.

The VPC endpoint is already attached to your VPC. You don't need to restrict the access to any other resources, because it is already restricted by itself.
Only the services inside your VPC can access to the VPC Endpoint.

Agreed. The OP could lockdown the VPC Endpoint with a Security Group that only allows Inbound access from the CIDR of the VPC, but it's pretty useless since the VPC Endpoint can only be accessed by resources within the VPC.
